go get a subdirectory with private azure repo
I want to require a specific module of a private azure repository. The module is in a subdirectory of said repository. This results in a required module that contains an undesired [...].git/[...] in the module path.
Following the Microsoft documentation for HTTPS I am able to get the complete repository but encounter the following issue when requiring a subdirectory.
.gitconfig
[url "https://user.name:token@dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/repo"]
    insteadOf = https://dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/repo

GOPRIVATE
"GOPRIVATE": "dev.azure.com"

Example 1
go get dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/repo.git/go
go: module dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/repo.git@upgrade found (v0.0.0), but does not contain package dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/repo.git/go


Expectation
require dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/repo/go
Example 2
go get dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/repo.git/go/pkg/mypkg@feature/#99999/mybranch
go: dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/repo.git/go/pkg/mypkg@feature/#98667/mybranch (v0.0.0) requires dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/repo.git/go/pkg/mypkg@v0.0.0: parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/repo/go/pkg/mypkg
                but was required as: dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/repo.git/go/pkg/mypkg

Expectation
require dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/repo/go/pkg/mypkg

Have tried to configure the files go.mod and .gitconfig reference the steps mentioned in the answer below? Does it work for you? @Valanthor

In the repository of your Go modules, open the subfolder "go" and ensure a "go.mod" file is existing.
module dev.azure.com/<organization-name>/<project-name>/_git/<repository-name>.git/go

go 1.14

See below example as reference:

The Go module.

go.mod file
module dev.azure.com/BriRanAdoOrg/ProjDemo/_git/myGoModule.git/MathCalc

go 1.14


Operators.go file
package Operators

func Addition(num1 float64, num2 float64) float64 {
  return num1 + num2
}

func Subtraction(num1 float64, num2 float64) float64 {
  return num1 - num2
}

func Multiplication(num1 float64, num2 float64) float64 {
  return num1 * num2
}

func Division(num1 float64, num2 float64) float64 {
  return num1 / num2
}





The Go app which needs to use the Go module.

The go.mod file
module myGoApp

go 1.14


The .gitconfig file
[url "https://<username>:<pat>@dev.azure.com/BriRanAdoOrg/ProjDemo/_git/myGoModule"]
    insteadOf = https://dev.azure.com/BriRanAdoOrg/ProjDemo/_git/myGoModule


The main.go file
package main

import (
   "fmt"
    "dev.azure.com/BriRanAdoOrg/ProjDemo/_git/myGoModule.git/MathCalc"
)

func main() {
    var num1 = 3.6
    var num2 = 1.2

    fmt.Printf("%v + %v = %.2f\n", num1, num2, Operators.Addition(num1, num2))
    fmt.Printf("%v - %v = %.2f\n", num1, num2, Operators.Subtraction(num1, num2))
    fmt.Printf("%v x %v = %.2f\n", num1, num2, Operators.Multiplication(num1, num2))
    fmt.Printf("%v ÷ %v = %.2f\n", num1, num2, Operators.Division(num1, num2))
}





The result.

The "go get dev.azure.com/BriRanAdoOrg/ProjDemo/_git/myGoModule.git/MathCalc" command can successfully download and parse the module.
The "go run main.go" command can successfully run the app.






I hoped to get around refactoring the project to include ".git" in package paths. Bute finally settled with it and that works fine as expected.
